# Kubernetes service external IP address remains pending with IBM Cloud (earlier called as Bluemix)

Tags: kubernetes, containers, ibm-cloud, ibm-cloud-kubernetes

I'm following an example from [Kubernetes in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/kubernetes-in-action) to run a simple docker image in kubernetes:

```
$ bx login --apikey @apiKey.json -a  https://api.eu-de.bluemix.net
$ bx cs cluster-config my_kubernetes
$ export KUBECONFIG=..my_kubernetes.yml
```

Next, run the container:

```
$ kubectl run kubia --image=luksa/kubia --port=8080 --generator=run/v1
$ kubectl expose rc kubia --type=LoadBalancer --name kubia-http
$ kubectl get service
$ kubectl get svc

NAME         CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   10.10.10.1    <none>        443/TCP          20h
kubia-http   10.10.10.12   <pending>     8080:32373/TCP   0m
```

Fifteen minutes later ...

```
NAME         CLUSTER-IP    EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes   10.10.10.1    <none>        443/TCP          20h
kubia-http   10.10.10.12   <pending>     8080:32373/TCP   15m
```

I don't have anything else running on the Kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to Chris Rosen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46075686/1033422), I was able to find a workaround:

```
$ bx cs workers my_kubernetes
OK
ID                 Public IP  Private IP  Machine Type State    Status
kube-par01-xxxxx   1.2.3.4    6.7.8.9     free         normal   Ready
```

Note the Public IP address: 1.2.3.4

Expose the service with NodePort:

```
$ kubectl expose rc kubia --type=NodePort --name kubia-http2
```

Check the NodePort details:

```
$ kubectl get svc
NAME          CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)          AGE
kubernetes    10.10.10.1     <none>        443/TCP          21h
kubia-http2   10.10.10.193   <nodes>       8080:31247/TCP   10s
```

Access the service using the exposed port on the worker Public IP address:

```
$ curl http://1.2.3.4:31247/
You've hit kubia-bjb59
```

Answer (score 5):

To close out the thread here, LoadBalancer cannot be used in a lite (aka free) cluster tier.  The differences between lite and standard clusters can be found here - https://console.bluemix.net/docs/containers/cs_planning.html#cs_planning.

Comment: Hi, I am using a paid account where I create a default cluster, use all 4 IPs which come by default and provisioned 4 new IPs. However, when I try to deploy my 5th application, it goes to pending state instead of using the newly provisioned IP. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Run the following to determine if there are any failure events.

```
kubectl describe svc kubia-http
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on the posts above I was getting the following steps to work:

Prerequisites: Create a free Kubernetes cluster in the IBM Cloud and follow the steps (you need to have the ibmcloud and kubectl installed and connect to the remote cluster first)

> kubectl get nodes

should return something like this

```
NAME           STATUS   ROLES    AGE     VERSION
10.76.197.55   Ready    <none>   4h18m   v1.18.10+IKS
```

Then,

1. kubectl apply -f https://k8s.io/examples/controllers/replication.yaml

> replicationcontroller/nginx created

2. kubectl expose rc nginx --type=NodePort

> service/nginx exposed

3. kubectl get svc

   NAME    TYPE       CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)        AGE

   nginx   NodePort   172.21.19.73           80:30634/TCP   70s
4. Note down the port, 30634 in my case
5. kubectl describe nodes |grep ExternalIP (to find out the external IP)

call IP:port

Have fun!

Answer (score 0):

If your purpose is to test your application by having it the accessible to the external world , I would suggest using the `NodePort` service which can be used in the free tier service.

More Info can be found here :  [Expose service to world](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_network_planning)